# spring resttemplate request object not mapping to rest controller

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-resttemplate

i have below resttempalte which invokes rest controller of another service..

```
    @Override
public ResponseEntity<String> callRestAPI(APIReqDataMO apiReqDataMO) {
    String apiURL = URIGenerator.getAPIURL(apiReqDataMO);
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    headers.set("Accept", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
    HttpEntity<?> request = new HttpEntity<>(apiReqDataMO.getRequestObject(), headers);
    ResponseEntity<String> httpRes = restTemplate.postForEntity(apiURL, request, String.class);
    return httpRes;
}
```

and in my service i have controller, which consumes above request..

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/targetService/createUser", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json")
public String fuzzerServiceAge(UserMO userMO) {
    System.out.println("---------------------age is -------------------------" + userMO.getAge());
    if (userMO.getAge() > 0) {
        System.out.println("error age greater than 0 ");
        return "invalid user age";
    } else if (userMO.getAge() == 0) {
        return "invalid user age";
        
    }
    return "user added successfully";
}
```

when i try my test.. the age which i am pushing through rest template is not getting mapped..and i am getting age as 0 always in my system.out.. what could be wrong in my code... and is there anything missing from configuration perspective..

EDIT -

```
public class APIReqDataMO {

private String restAPIURL;

private Object[] pathParam;

private Object[] requestParam;

private String requestType;

private String paramType;

private Object requestObject;

public String getParamType() {
    return paramType;
}

public void setParamType(String paramType) {
    this.paramType = paramType;
}

public String getRequestType() {
    return requestType;
}

public void setRequestType(String requestType) {
    this.requestType = requestType;
}

public Object getRequestObject() {
    return requestObject;
}

public void setRequestObject(Object requestObject) {
    this.requestObject = requestObject;
}

public String getRestAPIURL() {
    return restAPIURL;
}

public void setRestAPIURL(String restAPIURL) {
    this.restAPIURL = restAPIURL;
}

public Object[] getPathParam() {
    return pathParam;
}

public void setPathParam(Object[] pathParam) {
    this.pathParam = pathParam;
}

public Object[] getRequestParam() {
    return requestParam;
}

public void setRequestParam(Object[] requestParam) {
    this.requestParam = requestParam;
}
```

}

controller

```
    @PostMapping("/targetService/createUser")
public String fuzzerServiceAge(UserMO userMO) {
    
    System.out.println("--------------------- age is -------------------------" + userMO.getAge());
    if (userMO.getAge() > 0) {
        // return ResponseEntity.ok("Hello World!");
    } else if (userMO.getAge() == 0) {
        System.out.println(" it is else block");
        // return ResponseEntity.badRequest().build();
    }
    // return ResponseEntity.ok("user added successfully!");
    return "user added successfully";
}
```

usermo

public class UserMO {

```
@JsonProperty("name")
private String name;

@JsonProperty("age")
private int age;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}
```

}

Comment: Can you please share full controller class? Also please share UserMO and APIReqDataMO class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Issue**

There is an issue in API implementation. You are creating POST API and when the user will invoke this API by passing `UserMO` in the request body then mapping won't happen because the `@RequestBody` annotation is missing.

```
@PostMapping("/targetService/createUser")
public String fuzzerServiceAge(UserMO userMO) {
    
    System.out.println("--------------------- age is -------------------------" + userMO.getAge());
    if (userMO.getAge() > 0) {
        // return ResponseEntity.ok("Hello World!");
    } else if (userMO.getAge() == 0) {
        System.out.println(" it is else block");
        // return ResponseEntity.badRequest().build();
    }
    // return ResponseEntity.ok("user added successfully!");
    return "user added successfully";
}
```

**Solution**

If you are using `@RestController` annotation on top of the controller class then add `@RequestBody` annotation before `UserMO userMO` and try again.

Like this

```
@PostMapping("/targetService/createUser")
public String fuzzerServiceAge(@RequestBody UserMO userMO) {
//logic
}
```

if you are using `@Controller` annotation on top of the controller class then add `@ResponseBody` annotation on top of method `fuzzerServiceAge()` and  `@RequestBody` annotation before `UserMO userMO` and try again.

Like this

```
@PostMapping("/targetService/createUser")
@ResponseBody
public String fuzzerServiceAge(@RequestBody UserMO userMO) {
//logic
}
```

Comment: it worked.. seems like i missed spec here..